# Input tipo radio en Laravel collective y laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, radiobutton, laravelcollective

favor me ayudan tengo el siguiente formulario en laravel collective

```
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('militarysituation' , 'Situación Militar') }} <br>
<label>
{{ Form::radio('status', 'AL DÍA', ['class'=>'with-gap']) }} <span>AL DÍA</span>
</label>
<label>
{{ Form::radio('status', 'EXIMIDO', ['class'=>'with-gap']) }} <span>EXIMIDO</span>
</label>
<label>
{{ Form::radio('status', 'POSTERGADO', ['class'=>'with-gap']) }} <span>POSTERGADO</span>
</label>
</div>
```

y estoy recibiendo la variable ...

```
$person[0]->militarysituation
```

...con el valor "AL DÍA" desde el controlador
Pero no logro hacer que el radio button quede seleccionado, revisando con el inspector de elementos me salen todos los radio buttons como `"chequed"`

Comment: ¿la idea es que aparezca seleccionado por defecto `AL DÍA`?

Comment: Este dato viene desde la base de datos, la idea es que aparezca seleccionado el que viene en el controlador, en este caso debe aparecer AL DÍA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentacion que habla de la manera de crear formularios a partir de las etiquetas que provee laravel te indica como usarlas:

```
{{ Form::radio('name', 'value') }}
```

Tu estas usando estos valores para esos radio button (AL DIA, EXIMIDO, POSTERGADO)

Puedes crear una tabla para manejar los estados de esos radio button ejemplo:

```
Tabla Status
id                  1
descripcion         Al DIA

Tabla Person
id                  1
nombre             Pedro
id_status           1
```

Y apartir de ahi puedes iterar los registros

En tu controlador:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $person = person::find($id);
        $status = status::get();

        return view('person.edit')->with(['person' => $person, 'status' => $status]);
    }
```

En tu vista:

```
@foreach($status as $st)
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     {{Form::label('Status',$st->name)}}
     {{Form::radio('Status',$st->id,$st->id == $person->status_id ? true : false,['class'=>'with-gap'])}}
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Explicandote un poco lo que hice

- Hacer una consulta para obtener todos los status en la tabla status.
- Por cada status va a crear un radio button, se le asigna el valor que tiene en la base de datos (1,2,3, etc).
- El tercer parametro que recibe el radio button es la propiedad checked(true, false), valido si el valor del registro de la tabla person en el campo status_id es igual a valor que tiene el radio al momento de sen instanciado y si coincide le asigna el true a la propiedad checked

Comment: Excelente amigo esto me funciono! muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: {{ Form::radio('militarysituation', 'AL DÍA', 'AL DÍA' == $person[0]->militarysituation ? true : false, ['class'=>'with-gap']) }} <span>AL DÍA</span>

Comment: Así es como quedo con cada uno de los check y funciono perfecto, y para la proxima vez lo trabajare asi como me comentaste, el código queda mucho mas limpio, mil gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Buenas te dejo un ejemplo de input en checkbox al caso es el mismo, deberías usar old() de Laravel.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="al_dia" name="al_dia" value="1" {{ 
 1 == old('status', $item->status) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Puedes adaptar esto al tuyo te dejo por aquí la doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#old-input

Saludos